# How to handle contents in include syntax

Tags: php

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make a login using PHP. The content of mylogin.php is getting processed immediately just after loading the file index.php, I'm a bit confused in here. Thie screenshot below is the reponse just after loading the index file.

[response just after loading the index.php without doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGwPs.jpg)

index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Welcome     
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1> Please login</h1>
    <br>

    <!--
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Username: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/><br>
    <label>Password: </label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/><br><br>
    </form>
    -->

    <form method="post" action="">
    <label>Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
    <label>Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    include("mylogin.php");
    ?>
```

mylogin.php

```
<?php
    include("myconnection.php");

    $error="";
    if(empty($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if($_POST["username"] =='' || $_POST["password"]=='')
        {
            $error='Please fill the blanks!';

        }else
        {
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
            {
                $login_user=$_POST["$username"];    
                header("location: myhome.php");

                $error="Connected";

            }
            else
            {

            //$error="Incorrect Username/Password";
            //  echo"failed";

            }

        }
    }
    else
    {

        echo"failed to  submit2";

    }

?>
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection attacks. Consider using prepared statements. Also you seem to store the passwords in plain text. Consider using a hashing algorithm

Comment: You also would need to set start a session at the top of your php for the user to stay logged in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you include `mylogin.php` file like given in below code:
And there won't be this problem.

Welcome

```
<h1> Please login</h1>
<br>

<!--
<form action="" method="POST">
<label>Username: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/><br>
<label>Password: </label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/><br><br>
</form>
-->

<form method="post" action="">
<label>Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    include("mylogin.php");
}
?>
```

And of course, change your `if` condition of your `mylogin.php` file like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) OR you can change it 
if(!empty($_POST["submit"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a trouble with this condition `if(empty($_POST["submit"]))`. You want the negative condition of this, so you need something like :

`if(!empty($_POST["submit"]))` (with `!`)